# Automatically adding a decorator to each Python function in VSCode?

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

While trying to add the `@typechecked` property above all (of the 487) functions, I was experiencing some difficulties with finding the right replace command. I intend to go from:

```py
    def some_function(
```

to:

```py
    @typechecked
    def some_function(
```

However, when I do `Ctrl+H` and replace `def`  with:

```
@typechecked
def
```

The indentation of the def gets lost.

Hence I would like to ask:
**How can I add the property `typechecked above all functions in all` .py` files in vscode?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do a find/replace in VSCode with the following find and replace values:

```
     find: ^(\s*)(def [\w_]+\()
  replace: $1@typechecked\n$1$2
```

Answer (score 1):

use

Find: `^(\s*)def`

Replace: `$1@typechecked\n$1def`